Kurdish Letters "ێ", "ڵ", "ە" Not Rendering Correctly in PDF Generation
I am facing an issue with PDF generation in my FlutterFlow project, specifically related to Kurdish letters. The characters "ێ" (U+06CE), "ڵ" (U+06B5), and "ە" (U+06D5) are not rendering correctly when generating a PDF. These letters do not concatenate properly (i.e., they appear disjointed) in the PDF, although they render fine in the FlutterFlow UI and when exporting from applications like MS Word to PDF.
What I’ve Tried:
Fonts:
I have used several fonts that support Kurdish, including NotoSansArabic and NotoSansKurdish. These fonts work perfectly in the FlutterFlow UI and in other environments like MS Word.
PDF Libraries:
I’ve tested both the Syncfusion PDF package and the pdf/printing package in Flutter, but the issue persists across both libraries.
Steps to Reproduce:
Create a simple PDF with the following text:
لێ زان ێ ڵ ە
Use a font that supports Kurdish (e.g., NotoSansArabic or NotoSansKurdish).
Set the text direction to Right-to-Left (RTL).
Generate the PDF using either the Syncfusion or pdf/printing package.
Expected Outcome:
The Kurdish characters "ێ", "ڵ", and "ە" should be properly connected and shaped, just as they are in the FlutterFlow UI and other text-processing software like MS Word.
Actual Outcome:
In the generated PDF, these characters appear disjointed and do not concatenate properly with the surrounding text. This issue seems isolated to the PDF generation process.

Packages I've Tried:
Syncfusion Flutter PDF
pdf/printing
Similar Issues:
There is a similar unresolved issue regarding Kurdish text rendering in the following link, which may help better understand the problem:
Stimulsoft Kurdish Unicode Issue
Additionally, similar issues exist for Arabic characters, but the solutions did not address my specific case:
StackOverflow: Character Splitting in Arabic PDF
Request for Help:
I would appreciate any guidance or potential solutions for resolving this issue. I am not sure if the problem is related to font rendering, text encoding, or some limitation in the PDF generation libraries. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a workaround?

There is nothing you can do, those PDF packages do not implement proper Arabic text shaping. You have to contact the developers of those packages and ask them if they plan to support Arabic text shaping.

The solution to this is to build the content using HTML and CSS then convert it into pdf.

You can use this package, I think this can fixed your problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
